# Javascript compare two text fields

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to compare two Textfields with Javascript. But one of them must have a bigger value then the other one, like 5 = 4.

I dont know why.

```
        <script>

        document.getElementById("text1").addEventListener("keydown", testpassword2);

        function testpassword2() {

        var text1 = document.getElementById("text1");
        var text2 = document.getElementById("text2");

        if(text1.value == text2.value){  
        text2.style.borderColor = "#2EFE2E";
        }
        else{
        text2.style.borderColor = "red";
        }} 

       </script>
```

Comment: Please explain better what's not working or what's the expected behaviour

Comment: Post the code here or within a Stack Overflow snippet.

Comment: i edited the post.. or you can check this one http://jsfiddle.net/rm632Lqx/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some issues with your code:

- You only had an event listener on the first input. You'll need to add an event listener to the second input as well.
- The value on `keydown` won't contain the same value as on `keyup`. You'll need to do `keyup` to keep up with user input.

Working fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rm632Lqx/1/).

```js
document.getElementById("text1").addEventListener("keyup", testpassword2);
document.getElementById("text2").addEventListener("keyup", testpassword2);

function testpassword2() {
  var text1 = document.getElementById("text1");
  var text2 = document.getElementById("text2");
  if (text1.value == text2.value)
    text2.style.borderColor = "#2EFE2E";
  else
    text2.style.borderColor = "red";
}
```

```html
<body>                
<input type="text" id="text1" size="30">
<input type="text" id="text2" size="30">   
</body>
```

Comment: @RzeIMz Glad it works how you expected. Could you please mark my answer as correct?