# creating a display popup message in jquery if both the values are same in two input filed

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

How can i create in j query or java script if both the input values are same display popup message (That both the values are same) bootstrap please show with example.

Comment: Can you please be the first to show an example of what you tried? What was your research?  Where are you stuck exactly at what problem? If you missed it upon registration, please take a [tour], read [ask], than [edit] by providing a [mcve] of your specific issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this in html:

```
<input class="text" id="text1" type="text">
<input class="text" id="text2" type="text">
```

And using jQuery:

```
$("input.text").on('change paste input', function(){
      if($("#text1").val()==$("#text2").val()){
        alert("Equal");
      }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much.How can I display message in bootstrap modal can you please show me please or in html

Comment: @Aisha here i made a full example with the bootstrap modal https://jsfiddle.net/02fujgvq/9/

Answer (score 0):

You can find what you seek in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40772902/javascript-compare-two-text-fields#answer-40772989). It has done with **id** and the **keyup** event listner. Apart from that use **jQuery** will make that more easier.

```js
$( "#text1" ).bind( "keyup", function() {
  testpassword2();
});
$( "#text2" ).bind( "keyup", function() {
  testpassword2();
});

function testpassword2() {
  var text1 = document.getElementById("text1");
  var text2 = document.getElementById("text2");
  if ($("text1").val() == $("text2").val())
    text2.style.borderColor = "#2EFE2E";
  else
    text2.style.borderColor = "red";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>                
<input type="text" id="text1" size="30">
<input type="text" id="text2" size="30">   
</body>
```